# spss, what type of statistics can I do knowing the test of normality

Tags: anova, spss, descriptive-statistics

this is a small portion of the data...... total around 700

Ano,    Sexo,   Bips,   APT,    Peso,   Altura, IMC

7,00    1   46,00   AP  38,20   1,52    16,53

7,00    1   47,00   AP  39,20   1,56    16,11

7,00    1   61,00    AP     49,90   1,62    19,01

7,00    2   52,00   AP  51,60   1,60    20,16

7,00    2   50,00   AP  54,20   1,51    23,77

7,00    1   58,00   AP  39,20   1,54    16,53

7,00    2   54,00   AP  32,90   1,54    13,87

7,00    1   45,00   AP  39,00   1,59    15,43

12,00   1   30,00   AP  41,80   1,51    18,33

11,00   1   61,00  AP   47,70   1,56    19,60

7,00    2   54,00   AP  52,90   1,63    19,91

7,00    2   15,00    I  67,70   1,60    26,45

7,00    2   52,00   AP  45,40   1,60    17,73

8,00    2   72,00   I   47,80   1,69    16,74

Knowing that Ano is the grade of a student,  Sexo the sex 1 for Males 2 for Females, Bips the number of laps on a track, Peso is the weight of a student, Altura is the height of a student, IMC is the body mass index, APT the fitness of a person AP-fit I-not fit and AT-athlete.

What type of statistics can I do (like correlation,Anova, etc...) knowing this
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.